# Get random sample of customer IDs that meet multiple conditions

Tags: sql, random, sample

I have a SQL table of customer data including the following columns:

```
ID, age, postcode, sign up method
```

I need to get a random sample of this data that meet a number of conditions:

- 20% one age group, 30% another age group
- 50 % female
- x% one region, y% another region, z% another region etc.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I have created random samples before but not with these kind of conditions

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "random sample".  Is the overall data supposed to be 50% female, for instance, or do you want your sample to be 50% of the females in the data?  If you have females from the first age group, then your totals don't add to 100%.

Comment: It would have to be 50% female from each region and age group. It is random in that I only want c.10% of the full sample and it has to be a random 10% but that the sample meets the criteria above

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need n random rows from the SQL table.

- n1 rows from one age group
- n2 rows from another age group
- n3 rows from one region
- ...

---

Where n1 + n2 + n3 + ... = n.
For example PostgreSQL:

```
(SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE age > g0 AND age < g1
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT (n - n1))

UNION

(SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE age > g2 AND age < g3
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT (n - n2))

UNION

(SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE region = r0
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT (n - n3))
```

#g0, g1, g2, g3 are age parameters, r0 is region parameter